# VBA macro for range selection of graph creation

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a scrip to plot 300 graphs in excel. In de "Worksheet" the data is sorted by name. The list of names is shown in the "Master Sheet". 
VBA scripting is new for me but I have got this script from different questions on internet. I would like to make a connection between the graph range and the selection statement. Could you help me out with it?

```
Sub Startup()

    Sheets("Worksheet").Select
    ' Find the last row of data
    FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ' Loop through each row
    For x = 2 To FinalRow
        ' Decide if to select based on column A
        ThisValue = Sheets("worksheet").Cells(x, 1).Value
        ' SinglePath Configuration
        If ThisValue = Sheets("Master Sheet").Range("B" & 2) Then
            Sheets("worksheet").Range("A" & x, "C" & x).Select
        End If
        'Loop te create the SetSourceData selection for graph
    Next x

    Worksheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(Seclection) 'is selection a correct statement?
    ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
    ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet
    ws.Select

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here... could you clarify with what you want to do, what you have tried, and what is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Your code as is wont work... for example:

- you need to create the charts inside the loop. Your chart code comes after the loop is finished
- you have mis-spelt `Selection`
- you have stray variables (such as `ws` at the end)

*updated code*

The code below should be along the lines of what you need

If your conditiomns are met, a range (1rng1) is fed to a chart making sub, this sub automatically positions each chart in desending positions down the sheet where the data is (using the `lngCnt` variable).

```
Sub Startup()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngCnt As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set ws = Sheets("Worksheet")
' Find the last row of data
lngRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
' Loop through each row
For lngCnt = 2 To lngRow
' Decide if to select based on column A
    ThisValue = Sheets("worksheet").Cells(lngCnt, 1).Value
' SinglePath Configuration
    If ThisValue = Sheets("Master Sheet").Range("B" & 2) Then Call MakeChart(Range("A" & lngCnt, "C" & lngCnt), lngCnt)
'Loop te create the SetSourceData selection for graph
Next lngCnt

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub MakeChart(rng1 As Range, ByVal lngCnt)
Dim ch As ChartObject
Set ch = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(200, (lngCnt - 1) * 100, 250, 150)
With ch
    .Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
    .Chart.SetSourceData rng1
End With
End Sub
```